# How to check certain elements in a list with anonymous variables

Tags: prolog

Imagine having a list like `L = [1, 4, _, 5, _]`
If I would want to check if `4` is a member of this list, I could do this with: `member(4, L)`. This will return True, because there is a `4` in this list. However it returns true with every element I check, using member/2. This, of course, happens, because an anonymous variable can be matched with anything. So it will always return True. I was wondering if there would be a way I can remove all anonymous variables from list `L`. So a `NewList` would be `[1, 4, 5]`.

Comment: You can use [nonvar/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nonvar/1) to check if the variables are bound or unbound. To remove the unbound variables from the list, you can use one of the predicates that are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094500/prolog-remove-multiple-elements-from-a-list).

Comment: @AndersonGreen So like this? `subtract(L, [\+nonvar(_)], NewList)`

Comment: @Boomer, exactly or another way: `findall(X,(member(X,L),nonvar(X)),NewList).`

Comment: @Boomer, why not giving an answer ??

Comment: @coder I'm quite new to Stackoverflow and Prolog, but I'll do my best haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing variables from the list and then use `member/2` you could also opt to implement your own predicate that describes a `member/2`-like relation for non-variable elements:

```
nonvarmember(X,[Y|_]) :-
   nonvar(Y),                % only try to unify with X if Y is not a variable
   X=Y.
nonvarmember(X,[_Y|Ys]) :-
   nonvarmember(X,Ys).
```

Now let's see how this predicate works:

```
?- nonvarmember(4,[1,4,_,5,_]).
true ;
false.

?- nonvarmember(4,[1,_,_,5,_]).
false.

?- nonvarmember(4,[1,4,_,5,_,Z]).
true ;
false.
```

However, the first argument still can be a variable:

```
?- nonvarmember(X,[1,4,_,5,_,Z]).
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
false.

?- nonvarmember(X,[_,_,_]).
false.
```

But be aware that it does not matter if you remove the variable elements from the list first and subsequently use `member/2` or if you use `nonvarmember/2`, you run into the following problem: List-elements that are instantiated after you check for membership are not accounted for and hence might lead to unsound answers. The following example illustrates the problem:

```
?- A=4, nonvarmember(4,[A,B,C]).
A = 4 ;
false.

?- nonvarmember(4,[A,B,C]), A=4.
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to check if certain items are in a list that contains anonymous variables, you'd first need to (temporarily) remove all anonymous variables from that list. To do so you could use the built-in predicate `subtract/3` and `var/1`.

`subtract/3`: the first element being the list you want to check, the second element being a list containing elements you want to remove from the list and the third element being the resulting list.

`var/1`: contains only one element (X) and returns `True` if X is an unbound variable.

In this case we want to `subtract` every element (X) that is returning `True` when `var(X)`. In code, this is written as `var(_)`.

Now we simply fill in the `subtract/3` predicate like this: `subtract(L, [var(_)], NewList).`

`NewList` now only stores bound variables and `member/2` will now work as intented.

Comment: Instead if `\+nonvar` you could use `var/1` which succeeds in argument is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Swi-Prolog (at least) you can use include/3 and exclude/3 predicates to filter lists. You can use these predicates together with var/1 and nonvar/1, to remove variables from list.

In your particular case, checking whether 4 belongs to the list [1, 4, _, 5, _] could be done as follows:

```
L1 = [1, 4, _, 5, _],
exclude(var, L1, L2),
member(4, L2).
```